# Chrome support for new automatic metro split screen in Windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome, modern-ui, windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1 Pro if you are viewing a metro ("Windows 8") app (such as the Mail or Facebook applications) and you click on a URL, it will automatically open the IE Metro browser in a 50-50 split screen mode (assuming IE is your default browser).

This doesn't seem to work if you use Chrome as your default browser (even when using Chrome "Windows 8 mode").

Does anyone know if there is a way to get this working?

Comment: the apps must support this. Report it in the Chromium bugtracker.

Comment: Ok, reported here - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=313799